# Leaflet projection distortion

Tags: leaflet, geojson, projection

I have the following image which has a Gauss-Kruger zone 4 EPSG:31468.

[image: The image is in the Gauss-Kruger zone 4 EPSG:31468]

I already successfully displayed the image with Leaflat. Because Leaflat uses the projection EPSG:4326 I used the proj4.js Plugin which does a conversion from the projection. As expected there is a distortion. In picture two is the result from leaflat. Is it possible to remove the distortion that picture two looks like picture one?

[image: Result]